# how to handle error from google map api?

Tags: python, api, google-maps, error-handling

I am trying to query some direction information using the Google Map api. I want to be able to handle the NOT_FOUND situation when a non-existing location is accidentally put in. For example:

```
directions_result = gmaps.directions('bowcwe',
                                 'awef',
                                 waypoints = 'bjois',
                                 optimize_waypoints = True)
```

This returns an error message 'googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: NOT_FOUND'. How can I make an exception to this particular scenario? Thank you very much!

Comment: start by looking here: http://python-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gmaps.html#module-gmaps.errors

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly I can handle this error with a try statement or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The errors can be accessed through googlemaps.exceptions

Example code:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='AIza')
try:
    location = (50, 10)
    radius = 1000
    keyword = 'bar'
    returnedPlaces = gmaps.places_radar(location=location, radius=radius, keyword=keyword)

except googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError as err :
    print('API key is invalid')
```

I made the key 'AIza' to pass the first validity check and get an actual API error.

Hope this helps!